# Can I remove zobel network in LM386 circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, lm386

[image]

What happens if I omit this part?
Actually I don't have 10om resistor and I want to know is there any alternative?

ps: I know what is a zobel network. I want to know what happens if I omit it.

Comment: as stated in the answer (and as you know as you already call it a Zobel network), this is meant to compensate the reactance of the speaker.

Comment: This network adds a zero in the impedance expression including the loudspeaker and the series capacitor. Getting rid of it can jeopardize the 386 stability in some conditions.